# Custom BeanPropertyFilter - only serializing part of string

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, java-custom-serialization

I am in dire need of help. I am currently making some security restrictions on a resource in a Content API, where i need to either: Include properties, Truncate properties (if they are String.class) or remove properties from the object of serialization, based on a SecurityContext.

Im using Jackson as my json serializer, and have chosen to use a BeanPropertyFilter to check if each property should be serialized or not.

Now the remove, and include options are pretty straight forward, either i serialize the bean or not.

But the truncate option is a little worse. So here's what ive done so far regarding the serialization of the property.

```
@Override
public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, BeanPropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
    switch (determineFilterAction(writer)) {
        case INCLUDE_UNMODIFIED:
            writer.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, provider);
            break;
        case INCLUDE_TRUNCATED:
            Object value = writer.get(bean);
            if (!(value instanceof String)) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Annotation indicates truncate on " + writer.toString() + " which is not a string, but a " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and is unsupported");
            }
            JsonSerializer oldSerialzer= writer.getSerializer();
            writer.assignSerializer(new TruncateStringJsonSerializer());
            writer.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, provider);
            writer.assignSerializer(oldSerialzer);
            break;
        case REMOVE:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

Problem is, that there's a guard in the BeanPropertyWriter.assignSerializer() method, that will not allow me to switch in a new custom serializer for that one property.

Is there any way of hooking into, and modifying the bean-value? Or will i have to override Factories, and BeanPropertyWriter in order to override the assignSerializer() method (to avoid the serializer guard)?

I cant just annotate my properties with a special writer, since the object of serialization doesnt know anything about the SecurityContext, so there is no way to inject the securityContext into a custom serializer.

Is there any way at all to make this truncate option happen (without making it too hackish)?

Thanks in advance.

//Best regards, Martin.

*UPDATE*

Based on StaxMan's answer, i have updated the method to look like this, and it seems to work. At least all my tests run correctly. Will test further on development application-servers.

```
@Override
public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, BeanPropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
    switch (determineFilterAction(writer)) {
        case INCLUDE_UNMODIFIED:
            writer.serializeAsField(bean, jgen, provider);
            break;
        case INCLUDE_TRUNCATED:
            Object value = writer.get(bean);
            if (!(value instanceof String)) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Annotation indicates truncate on " + writer.toString() + " which is not a string, but a " + value.getClass().getSimpleName() + " and is unsupported");
            }
            String valueString = (String) value;
            jgen.writeFieldName(writer.getName());
            jgen.writeString(StringUtils.abbreviate(valueString, MAX_LENGTH));
            break;
        case REMOVE:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i could just override the default BeanPropertyWriter that jackson initializes, with my own, and register it, it could override the guard that prevents me from switching out the serializers. But i cant find anyone how has done this on the web. (At least not without implementing own, factory provider AND own factory). Wich im not too fond of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, do not even try to call `assignSerializer`: that is a bad idea in multi-threaded environment -- there is just a single instance of that serializer, and even if you could call it, it'd just cause you a bizarre exception in cases where two serializations were done concurrently.

But perhaps you should consider approaching this from different direction: since you are already finding `String` value, why not directly write truncated value using `JsonGenerator`?
Or, if you prefer, delegate to something that does the write; but since you are calling it, it need not be a `JsonSerializer` or anything.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This helped, and worked. Its a tad ugly, just doing a manual write, i would have prefered to let the jackson setup handle it all.

Good to know about the assignSerializer, i thought jackson could handle this, when it can handle switching out serializers with @JsonSerialize(using = SomeCustomSerializer.class).. There's even a note in the source code, commenting on weather or not to remove the guard in a future version. :)

Comment: Yeah, it is not always clear what can and especially what should be done. Maybe that method should have a warning note. Plus basic `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer` should emphasize the fact that instances need to be thread-safe, as instances are shared for concurrent use.